# Is DDOS more common than DOS?

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos

Which attack takes place more often over the internet? I would have assumed DDOS due to the amount of botnets around today.

Comment: DDoS is a subset of DoS. It *cannot* happen more often.

Comment: @cpast - conceptually, DDoS is a subset of DoS.  But the OP might (ambiguous) be referring to number of DDoS attacks vs. plain non-distributed DoS attacks, such as those that only require a handful of packets from a single attacker to freeze up a web server.  In that case, I'd say DDoS is more prevalent in the news, but I don't know if there are metrics for a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that DoS attacks are significantly more common, I should also point out that a packet flood is not the only form of DoS / DDoS attack.

For example, I know of a fairly popular php product ( a Video encoding / gallery product, not going to name names since this is still undisclosed) which even in its current revision can be massaged correctly into fork-bombing the server that is running into oblivion.

A DDoS requires a botnet or multiple machines to do this so the barrier to entry on this is higher.